# Function to generate several variables from repeated measures

Tags: r, functional-programming, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have data showing results of 5 tests (`pub1` to `pub5`) each taking integer values between 0 and 6, and which were repeated at 5 different ages (`age1` to `age5`). That is, `pub1` was done at `age1`....`pub5` was done at `age5`

I need to create 6 new columns/variables (`age_v1` to `age_v6`) that should show the age at which a person first had a certain score of `pub`:

1. age_v1: age at first occurrence of a value of 1 on any of the `pub` variables
2. age_v2: age at first occurrence of a value of 2 on any of the `pub` variables
3. age_v3: age at first occurrence of a value of 3 on any of the `pub` variables
4. age_v4: age at first occurrence of a value of 4 on any of the `pub` variables
5. age_v5: age at first occurrence of a value of 5 on any of the `pub` variables
6. age_v6: age at first occurrence of a value of 6 on any of the `pub` variables

For example, for individual x, `age_v5` will equal `age3` if the first time they score a value of 5 on any of the `pub` variables is in `pub3`

```
    #Simulate example data
    library(tidyverse)
    N <- 2000
    data <- data.frame(id = 1:2000,age1 = rnorm(N,6:8),age2 = rnorm(N,7:9),age3 = rnorm(N,8:10),
               age4 = rnorm(N,9:11),age5 = rnorm(N,10:12),pub1 = rnorm(N,1:4),pub2 = rnorm(N,1:4),
               pub3 = rnorm(N,1:4),pub4 = rnorm(N,1:4),pub5 = rnorm(N,1:4))

   data <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pub")), funs(round(replace(., .< 0, NA), 0)))
```

Comment: It is unclear from the description what you want as output?  Initially, I thought that you want to create the columns in one step, but while looking at your description, it is a bit different.  Can you show the expected output

Comment: Thanks - i have edited my question slightly to hopefully make my point clearer. I am looking to create the columns in one step, the new columns should take different values of age1:age5 depending on the first appearance of the specific value in pub1:pub5

Comment: I think it is better to have a small example and show the corresponding expected output.  The input data you showed can be created with `data %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("pub")), funs(round(replace(., .< 0, NA), 0)))`

Comment: In the columns that you want to create, is it a binary column/columns or age values corresponding to it, ??  It is confusing

Comment: The new columns should be age values - they should take the value of age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the data more easily instead of many steps

```
i1 <- grepl('^pub', names(data)) # index for pub columns
i2 <- grepl('^age', names(data)) # index for age columns
data[i1] <- lapply(data[i1], function(x) pmax(round(., 0), 0)) # data rounding
# instead of NA values, replaced with 0 as it is easier to get the column index
```

Loop through the 1:6, in a `list`, extract the column index corresponding to the `first` match for the value in each row of 'pub', `cbind` with row index and extract the corresponding 'age' value.  If there is no match in a row, it will be NA (using the 'j2' index) and assign those to create new columns in the 'data'

```
data[paste0("age_v", 1:6)] <- lapply(1:6, function(i) {
         j1 <- max.col(data[i1] == i, 'first')
         j2 <- rowSums(data[i1] == i) == 0
         data[i2][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), j1 *(NA^j2))]
  })
```